# Return something instead of return null

Tags: java

I am trying to split a string

Here is the items
but if a string was `GTA ONE`
I  want to ignore the `ONE`
just take the input `GTA`

print out the whole games that start with `GTA`

```
GTA ONE
GTA THREE
GTA FOUR
GTA FIVE
```

but it cannot fail for "GTA ONE"

The bug is that when I type "GTA".

it does return all the matching "GTA" and null.

I want to eliminate null.

The value null is only supposed to return when there's is no game. 
Can someone explain to me?
Thanks.

```
class Game{
   private String name;
   public Game(String name{
    this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){return name};

   public boolean hasGame(String name){
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name);
    }

   @Override
   public String toString(){
    return name + " " + edition;
   }
}


class Shop{
private LinkedList<Game> games = new LinkedList<Game>();
public Shop(){
games.add(new Game("GTA ONE");
games.add(new Game("Sonic One");
games.add(new Game("GTA THREE");
games.add(new Game("GTA FOUR");
games.add(new Game("GTA FIVE");
}

public static void main(String args[]){
   new Shop().sell();
}

private Game game(String name){
   ArrayList<Product> tempGames = new ArrayList<Product>();
        boolean fix2 = false;
        for(Game game: games)
            if(game.hasGame(name)){

               return game;
            }
            else if(game.getName().contains(name)){
                 tempGames.add(game);
                 fix2 = true;
            }
        if(fix2)
            for(Game tempGame: tempGames)
                 System.out.println(tempGame);
        return null;
   }
}
private void sell() {
        String name = "GTA";
        Game game = game(name);
        if(game != null){
               System.out.println("Selling " + name);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println(name + " does exist in the store.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `name` supposed to be `GTA` and `edition`, `ONE`? Or do you store the entire String in `name` when you input?

Comment: You need to provide more of your code to give a clearer picture of what you issue may be.

Comment: @darclander you are right it should be the whole string sry. I just edit it.

Comment: @pczeus that's all the code I have. I can answer which concern you

Comment: Which `game.getName()` gives you NullPointerException? There are too many of it.

Comment: @user3437460 oh yeah sry.

Comment: I don't think `fix = false` is needed in the `if-statement` since if you enter that you just `return game;` anyways?

Comment: I think the reason you get `null` is because of this line `tempProducts.add(product);`. You are adding `product` to the array but you haven't defined what product is? The return value for game() seems to be null aswell?

Comment: @ratRedTears did that resolve the error?

Comment: @darclander no bro, still return null. I think because it's System.out.println(tempGame) and so there's no return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212821/discussion-between-darclander-and-ratredtears).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not comparing the full name, you need to use `contains` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase` in `hasGame`.

Apart from this, the methods, `sell` and `game` also have to be corrected to match your requirement. The method, `game` needs to return a `List<Game>` and accordingly you need to make changes in the method, `sell`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Game {
    private String name;

    public Game(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean hasGame(String name) {
        return this.name.contains(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Shop {
    private LinkedList<Game> games = new LinkedList<Game>();

    public Shop() {
        games.add(new Game("GTA ONE"));
        games.add(new Game("Sonic One"));
        games.add(new Game("GTA THREE"));
        games.add(new Game("GTA FOUR"));
        games.add(new Game("GTA FIVE"));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.sell("GTA");
        System.out.println();
        shop.sell("XYZ");
    }

    private List<Game> game(String name) {
        List<Game> tempGames = new ArrayList<Game>();
        for (Game game : games) {
            if (game.hasGame(name)) {
                tempGames.add(game);
            }
        }
        return tempGames;
    }

    private void sell(String name) {
        List<Game> games = game(name);
        if (!games.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Selling: ");
            for (Game game : games) {
                System.out.println(game);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " does not exist in the store.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Selling: 
GTA ONE
GTA THREE
GTA FOUR
GTA FIVE

XYZ does not exist in the store.
```